# Editing data (order line's items) in IEnumerable View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, ienumerable

**My Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SNW.Models.CustomerOrderInfo
{
    public class MemberOrder : CustomerOrder
    {
        public new int customerOrderID { get; set; }
        [..]
        public int customerOrderLineID { get; set; }
        public int productID { get; set; }
        [..]
        public double customerOrderQtyMin { get; set; }
        public double customerOrderQtyMax { get; set; }
        [..]
    }
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
[..]
using SNW.Models;
using SNW.Models.CustomerOrderInfo;

namespace SNW.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerOrderController : Controller
    {
        private DBModelContainer db = new DBModelContainer();
        [HttpPost, ActionName("SaveChanges")]
        public ActionResult SaveChanges([Bind(Include = "customerOrderQtyMax")] SNW.Models.CustomerOrderInfo.MemberOrder line)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    db.Entry(line).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("CustomerOrder");
            }
            return View(line);
        }
    }
}
```

**My View** (*CustomerOrder.cshtml*):

```
@model IEnumerable<SNW.Models.CustomerOrderInfo.MemberOrder>
[..]
    @foreach (var MemberOrder in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@MemberOrder.productID</td>
        <td>@MemberOrder.productName</td>
        [..]
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMin)</td>
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "CustomerOrder", new { id = MemberOrder.customerOrderLineID }))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderLineID)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax)
                <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-default" />
            }
        </td>
    [..]
    </tr>
```

**Rendered View:**

[image]

**The Problem:**

Whenever I change Max value of Order Line and click "+" to update it in database, it doesn't work.

The `line` values in `SaveChanges()` method comes as either 0 or null, including `customerOrderQtyMax` value which is 0.0, but DB update doesn't happen either - former values are being shown again.

So my question is, how do I pass only `customerOrderQtyMax` input value to DB from this IEnumerable View? I want' to be able to amend order (or shopping cart if you wish) values right in *CustomerOrder.cshtml* page.

**What have I tried so far:**

1. [Updating Related Data with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954882/1380473)
2. [Various tutorials on Youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22977617/1380473)
3. Comparing `SaveChanges()` method to `Edit()` method generated from DB Model by EF6 for `CustomerOrderLines` entity. The later is not using IEnumerables<> and it has it's own View (*Edit.cshtml*).
4. Added an extra `HiddenFor()` field in my View as my Order Lines' primary keys are composed of `customerOrderLineID` and `customerOrderID` attributes.

`@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "CustomerOrder", new { id = MemberOrder.customerOrderLineID }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderLineID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderID)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax)
        <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-default" />
    }`

Thank you for your help, guys!

### EDIT:

I've changed the code in `SaveChanges()` method quite a few times, but here is what errors I received:

1. Reference to `SNW.Models.CustomerOrderInfo.MemberOrder` in `public ActionResult SaveChanges([Bind(Include = "customerOrderQtyMax")] SNW.Models.CustomerOrderInfo.MemberOrder line)` awards me with following error: 
   *{"The entity type MemberOrder is not part of the model for the current context."}* probably because it's my custom made Model which inherits from `CustomerOrder` Model, because

   - `CustomerOrder` can be overwritten by EF Model generator
   - I need to use extra custom made properties for calculations
2. Changed `SNW.Models.CustomerOrderInfo.MemberOrder` to original `CustomerOrderLine` and received following error: *{"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."}*.

   - `CustomerOrderLine` is generated by EF Model generator and I want its properties to merge with `CustomerOrder` to be able to edit Order's information in one window rather then going to Edit View for every single row (order line). That's why I made custom `SNW.Models.CustomerOrderInfo.MemberOrder` Model.
   - Now `SaveChanges()` is `public ActionResult SaveChanges([Bind(Include = "customerOrderQtyMax")] CustomerOrderLine line)`
3. @Jasen. **HTTP POST Header** Thank you.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:64778/CustomerOrder/SaveChanges/8
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview parsed
POST /CustomerOrder/SaveChanges/8 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:64778
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 68
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:64778
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:64778/CustomerOrder/CustomerOrder
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,lt;q=0.6
Cookie: .ASPXFORMSAUTH=F44D36B23D1EA17ABB24DEEC4AFA7B09FD2D7B3EEB8D9C57D95561E9A9B334F4BA90F46AEAC2E2DE23958998B3F888342E507B92484C45D990CD0FD08D38F8D8D994CC8F5C231A0144DE4A7B89A286A1AFFEE765C86C856E71403FF94FDF873E
Form Dataview parsed
MemberOrder.customerOrderLineID=8&MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax=78
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcRG9uYXRhc1xTb3VyY2VcUmVwb3NcU291bmRzTmljZVdob2xlZm9vZHNcU05XXFNOV1xDdXN0b21lck9yZGVyXFNhdmVDaGFuZ2VzXDg=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 09 Apr 2014 21:03:23 GMT
Content-Length: 17180
```

**HTML Form:**

`<form action="/CustomerOrder/SaveChanges/8" method="post">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field customerOrderLineID must be a number." data-val-required="The customerOrderLineID field is required." id="MemberOrder_customerOrderLineID" name="MemberOrder.customerOrderLineID" type="hidden" value="8">
    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field customerOrderQtyMax must be a number." data-val-required="The customerOrderQtyMax field is required." id="MemberOrder_customerOrderQtyMax" name="MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax" type="text" value="3">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

    <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-default">
</form>`

4. Tried a solution from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954882/1380473) and changed the code to 

       `[HttpPost, ActionName("SaveChanges")]
       public ActionResult SaveChanges([Bind(Include = "customerOrderQtyMax")] CustomerOrderLine line) // whitelist fields
       {
           CustomerOrderLine lineTemp = new CustomerOrderLine() 
           {
               customerOrderQtyMax = line.customerOrderQtyMax
           };
           if(ModelState.IsValid)
           {
                   db.Entry(lineTemp).State = EntityState.Added;
                   db.SaveChanges();
                   return RedirectToAction("CustomerOrder");
           }
           return View(lineTemp);
       }`

And now got this error: *{"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (\"c1snw\".\"CustomerOrderLines\", CONSTRAINT \"FK_ProductCustomerOrderLine\" FOREIGN KEY (\"productID\") REFERENCES \"Products\" (\"productID\") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)"}*, which probably means... well, I'm not sure if correct line is selected from DB using this code and whether it is trying to Update or Add a new line. Will check that.

### SOLUTION:

@Jasen's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22977617/1380473) of using `Prefix="MemberOrder"` in Bind helped to get code working!

However, I got rid of `Include=` statement in Bind, because it only worked when all line's attributes, that are not initially empty (*null* or 0) are included, and since I need all of them, I removed `Include=` in Controller and added more `HiddenFor` fields in the View. If I haven't had done this, Controller would attempt to change initial values to *null*) or 0.

#### Final code:

**My Controller:**

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("SaveChanges")]
public ActionResult SaveChanges([Bind(Prefix="MemberOrder")] CustomerOrderLine line) // whitelist fields
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            db.Entry(line).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("CustomerOrder");
    }
    return View(line);
}
```

**My View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "CustomerOrder", new { id = MemberOrder.customerOrderLineID }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderLineID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => MemberOrder.productID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMin)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyActual)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax)
    <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

#### More resources on similar issues:

1. [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding - Part1 (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159749/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-Part)
2. [How to use Bind Prefix? (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317523/how-to-use-bind-prefix)
3. [ASP.Net MVC3 Model Binding IEnumerable with Editor Template (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831552/asp-net-mvc3-model-binding-ienumerablet-with-editor-template)
4. [How to bind multiple prefixes? (ASP.NET)](http://forums.asp.net/t/1846038.aspx?How%20to%20bind%20multiple%20prefixes)
5. [Multiple submit buttons with ASP.NET MVC: final solution](http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/)

Comment: Before debugging the DB save you'll need to successfully send the data to the controller action. What does the `SaveChanges()` POST request headers look like?

Comment: Thank you, @Jasen. Just updated my post with more information.

Comment: Your POST is for `CustomerOrder`. You're looking for the `SaveChanges` (which matches your action name) request instead.

Comment: Sorry, @Jasen. Reposted correct headers now.

Comment: You are missing (have not shared) part of the header. The header section **Form Data** is what's of interest to you. It will display the form fields sent and the parameter names (which will bind to your model).

Comment: @Jasen. Finally! Used different approach of getting POST Headers :) 
`Form Dataview parsed
MemberOrder.customerOrderLineID=8&MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax=78`

Comment: Ok, now that we see the data is sent, are you seeing that at your server-side break point in `SaveChanges` just before `if(ModelState.IsValid)`?

Comment: In Visual Studio I see `+  Form {MemberOrder.customerOrderLineID=8&MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax=44} System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection {System.Web.HttpValueCollection}` while debugging before `if(ModelState.IsValid)`. this > base > Request > Form Is that correct? Or should I look somewhere else? @Jasen

Comment: You might try adding `customerOrderLineID`, the row id, to the Bind Include list.

Comment: Didn't helped. I also tried adding all attributes to the Bind Include list, but received same error: _{"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."}_ 
Form Data shows all values being submitted correctly, only they don't reach `SaveChanges()` method for some reason as `CustomerOrderline line` object holds empty values for each attribute. @Jasen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem here is the for loop is messing up the posted variable names so that automatic binding will fail. So you'll need to add the `Prefix` parameter to your Bind.

```
[Bind(Prefix="MemberOrder", ...)]
```

The Prefix you specified in the EditorFor helper in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => MemberOrder.customerOrderQtyMax)
```

Also, add the row ID to the Bind Include.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("SaveChanges")]
public ActionResult SaveChanges(
    [Bind(Prefix="MemberOrder", Include = "customerOrderLineID,customerOrderQtyMax")]
        SNW.Models.CustomerOrderInfo.MemberOrder line)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(line).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("CustomerOrder");
    }
    return View(line);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jasen! You were right, the main problem was the Prefix. I added Solution bit to my post. Hopefully it will help others too.